# Bootstrap visible-md-inline-block doesn't apply the correct css style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my website responsive, so I want to hide a specific col-md-6 element on xs and sm devices. I tried using 'visible-md-inline-block' in order to do that but bootstrap automatically applies 'display: none' to the element even though i'm on a large screen device. Am I doing it wrong? Can someone explain this?

You can see a live demo here: http://acvix.com/development/temp (near the phone image, there should be another paragraph on the left similar to the visible one on the right)

Comment: Please provide the code in the body of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` classes to hide the `lefterino` element on `xs` and `sm` screen sizes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 lefterino hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <p><span>Daily Posts</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I thought mixing them wouldn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy coding ; -)